# Staking reward distribution in a month

Tags: solidity, tokens, erc-20, staking

I was just wondering, how would I be able to make a staking function that, after one month, distributes "x"% to the locked up stake holders?

Is it something to do with `now`  and `blocktimestamp`?

Comment: Yes with now, but it's not 100% accurate. And someone musst send a tx to call that function. And the condition should be checked e.g. now is bigger than timeOfStake + (30 days in seconds = 2592000or in milliseconds) I don't remember if now is in seconds or milliseconds

Comment: If it's not 100&, we shouldn't use it correct? I wonder how other projects do it.

Comment: most of them use it. the problem is in seconds or minutes delay (until your distribute-transaction gets mined and included in the block). the other problem is timestamp comes from miners, so you should trust that miners use the right timestamp in the produced block (which what they do)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use something like:

```
//initialize
uint timeOfStake = block.timestamp;
uint timeToDistribute = timeOfStake + 30 days;

//for later invocation
function distribute() public{
    require(block.timestamp >= timeToDistribute);
    distribute();
}

function distribute(){
    //distribution logic
    //...
}
```

Comment: That would just set the timeOfStake to the block.stamp and wont update it, wouldn't it? That would make it always lower than timeToDistribute because it isn't updated.

Comment: Yeah but I am checking against block.timestamp not against timeOfStake.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't read it correctly! Sorry!

Comment: No worries, glad you solved your problem :)